# RSpec error "undefined method `respond_with'..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am following the tutorials http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_three
But when I ran the controller test `bundle exec rspec spec/controllers` I am getting undefined method error:

```
Failures:

 Api::V1::UsersController GET #show 
 Failure/Error: it { should respond_with 200 }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `respond_with' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000005d6f650>
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.08435 seconds
 2 examples, 1 failure
```

Please help

Edit:
The below is the contents of my spec file

users_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  before(:each) { request.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.marketplace.v1" }

  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      get :show, id: @user.id, format: :json
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
    end

    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end
end
```

Comment: What is in your spec file?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm : I have edited and updated the contents. This is how my users_controller_spec.rb file looks like. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here since we are dealing with `response codes` you can use-

`it { expect(response).to have_http_status(200) }`

instead of `it { should respond_with 200 }`

Here no need of `shoulda-matchers` gem as well.

> Ref - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it. It looks like using older version of shoulda-matchers helps. I changed the `Gemfile` to `gem "shoulda-matchers", "~>2.5"`

Answer (score 3):

Having this error after upgrade my old rails app to `rails 5.0`. then add the following configuration into `spec_helper.rb` and now its working fine.

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
   config.integrate do |with|
     with.test_framework :rspec
     with.library :rails
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not finding shoulda methods, I'd make sure you have this in your `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActionController, { type: :model, file_path: /spec\/controllers/})
```

Or it might be there but commented-out.

Comment: I just included the above piece of code in spec_helper.rb but still I am getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: It work for me, in case when bin/rake spec pass, but bin/rspec fail with "undefined method 'respond_with'"

Comment: @eagleas in that case I'd make sure if the rake task is doing `require 'spec_helper'` or `require 'rails_helper'`, you put those in `.rspec` too (as `--require spec_helper` or `--require rails_helper`).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error from shoulda-matchers gem, try to update to the latest version.

Also make sure that it comes after RSpec in your gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```